# Port 88 forwarding for offsite users to authenticate with DC

Tags: authentication

So after researching, I decided to do some port forwarding on port 88 from offsite Mikrotik routers using public IP address x.x.x.x to port 88 in the main office, so users can authenticate with the domain controller for interactive logon.

If port forwarding is done from port 88 using specific real IP x.x.x.x (field office 1) to port 88 real IP y.y.y.y (main office) the offsite user then should be able to authenticate for credentials.

My concern is how far this setup can be vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never expose authentication server onto the internet.
It is safer to expose the VPN server and then make users connect to VPN first to your office network.
You can connect your two networks via VPN as well.
Use well proven, secure VPN appliance, there are some cheap software ones like OpenVPN.

VPNs are also prime target for hackers. Therefore it's good to have limited number of networks which can access your VPN (firewall), keep it always up to date, do not allow to connect without user certificate (so you need issue for each user SSL cert, this way brute force wont work on VPN), enforce good AV software for each client accessing it.

Regarding exposing SSL for the VPN, note that there used to be numerous SSL exploits, so having  user certs, firewall and updates is really important.

Users should be able to logon to Windows using domain credentials offline (without VPN), then logon to VPN and proceed with launching Outlook and using Active Directory and stuff.